# How to check if the last element of a list is a member of another list?

Tags: haskell

I'm having some troubles with lists.

I have the following lists of lists:

```
sentence = [['t','h','e'], ['b','o','y'],['i','s'],['h','a','p','p','y']]

shortVowel = [['a'], ['e'], ['y']]
```

I need to make an if statement that checks 2 things:

(1) if an element x is a member of the last "sublist" (whose, of course, is the last element of the main list),

and (2) if an element (a sublist) of the list `shortVowel` is the last member of the last sublist.

The (1) I was able to do with `elem 'а' (last sentence))` (checking if 'a'is a member of `['h','a','p','p','y']`, which it is.

The (2) is the one I don't know how to get.

For exemple, the last element of the last sublist in `sentence` is `y` (from happY). And `y` is also a sublist in the `shortVowel` list.

I need to check exactly this.

I try some things, like `elem shortVowel (last sentence)`, but it didn't work.

This is my current code:

```
import Data.List

sentence = [['t','h','e'], ['b','o','y'],['i','s'],['h','a','p','p','y']]

shortVowel = [['a'], ['e'], ['y']]

main =  if ((elem 'а' (last sentence)) || (elem 'о' (last sentence)) || (elem 'у' (last sentence)) && (elem shortVowel (last sentence)))
           then putStrLn "A"
        else if (elem 'р' (last sentence))
           then putStrLn "B"
        else putStrLn "C"
```

Comment: cannot check now, but does this compile? Wrong types at `elem shortVowel (last sentence)` since `elem :: a -> [a] -> Bool` but  `shortVowel :: [[Char]]` and `last sentence :: [Char]`. Also, I think your are messing the types. You say: _and `y` is also a sublist in the `shortVowel` list_... `y` is a `Char` not a sublist. Try something like `map (== [last (last sentence)]) shortVowel`

Comment: Quick tip: String literals `"abc"` are equivalent internally to lists `['a','b','c']`. So you could also write `sentence = ["the", "boy", "is", "happy"]`.

Comment: As for your question: The `any` function is useful in cases like this. `any f list` is true if _any_ element of `list` returns true when given to `f`. So e.g. `any (\x -> x > 1) [0,1,2]` returns `True`, since there is at least one element of `[0,1,2]` which satisfies `\x -> x > 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing `shortVowel = [['a'], ['e'], ['y']]` I would write `shortVowel' = ['a', 'e', 'y']`. Which is the same as `shortVowel' = "aey"`. Now do

```
or [x == last $ last sentence | x <- shortVowel']
```

The above checks if any of the elements in `shortVowel` is the last element of the last word in your sentence. If you want to check it for all short vowels then do

```
[(x, x == last $ last sentence) | x <- shortVowel']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things you could do:

- Deal with handling errors. Both the list of words and the last word itself could be empty.

  `last` is a [partial function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_partial_functions) and can crash at run-time.
- Move your logic into a pure function separate from `main :: IO`.

  Make the example string a parameter of the function.

  And deal with extracting the last word from the sentence separately.

Here's an example of that:

```
module Main where

-- | `lastMay [x,y,z] == Just z` and `lastMay [] == Nothing`.
lastMay :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastMay [] = Nothing
lastMay [x] = Just x
lastMay (_:xs) = lastMay xs

-- | `endsWithShortVowel "yay" == True` and `endsWithShortVowel "moo" == False`.
wordEndsWithShortVowel :: String -> Bool
wordEndsWithShortVowel s = case lastMay s of
  Nothing -> False -- No letters in word!
  Just c -> c `elem` "aey"

sentenceEndsWithShortVowel :: [String] -> Bool
sentenceEndsWithShortVowel s = case lastMay s of
  Nothing -> False -- No words in sentence!
  Just w -> wordEndsWithShortVowel w

main :: IO ()
main =
  if sentenceEndsWithShortVowel exampleSentence
    then ...
    else ...

exampleSentence :: [String]
exampleSentence = words "the boy is happy"
```

Then, for example, making the program receptible to strings from standard input becomes easier:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  sentence <- words <$> getLine
  if sentenceEndsWithShortVowel sentence
    then ...
    else ...
```

**Note:** Be careful of indentation levels when you combine `do` and `if-then-else`.